# ¿Por qué se dice "dar calabazas a alguien" cuando se le suspende o rechaza?

Tags: etimología, expresiones, españa

Es esta una expresión con la que entré en contacto gracias a los tebeos de [Zipi y Zape](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zipi_y_Zape):

[image: Calabazas]

Según el diccionario:

> **[dar calabazas a alguien](http://dle.rae.es/?id=6fFiXov)**
>
> 1. loc. verb. coloq. Reprobarlo en un examen.
> 2. loc. verb. coloq. Desairarlo o rechazarlo cuando requiere de amores.

Buscando un poco parece que hay [algunas historias](http://blogs.20minutos.es/yaestaellistoquetodolosabe/dar-calabazas-cual-es-el-origen-de-esta-expresion/) que dicen que la calabaza es un "antiafrodisiaco", y que en la Edad Media se llegó a recomendar su consumo para alejar los pensamientos lascivos, y en algunas regiones incluso se llegaban a ofrecer platos a base de calabaza para rechazar a los pretendientes de una hija de la familia.

¿Puede alguien aportar alguna otra explicación o completar esta si es correcta?

Nota: he añadido la etiqueta [españa](/questions/tagged/espa%c3%b1a) porque no sé si se conoce fuera de aquí. Podéis poner o quitar etiquetas si se usa en otros países.

Comment: En todas partes aparece prácticamente el mismo texto, lo que nunca explican es por qué se usa en los exámenes. En algún sitio también hacen referencia al _"Vocabulario de refranes..."_ de Gonzalo Correas para explicar el origen en la costumbre de aprender a nadar con calabazas pero en ese libro solo encuentro la expresión "Nadar sin calabazas" que no creo que tenga nada que ver con "dar calabazas"

Comment: Coincido con blonfu. Toas las referencias que he podido encontrar son casi identicas (compara la de la pregunta del _20 Minutos_ con esta del [Muy Interesante](http://www.muyinteresante.es/cultura/arte-cultura/articulo/ide-donde-viene-la-expresion-qdar-calabazas). La más "oficial" (dependiendo de la validez que le quiera dar a las web tipo _wiki_) que he podido encontrar sería [Wikilengua](http://www.wikilengua.org/index.php/dar_calabazas) que una vez más explica exactamente lo mismo.

Comment: ¿Tal vez tenga relación con la 6ª acepción de calabaza: "6. f. coloq. Persona inepta y muy ignorante."?

Comment: Me ha sorprendido esto: [Fear The Pumpkin: In Ukraine, It's The Big Kiss-Off](http://www.npr.org/templates/story/story.php?storyId=130890830), porque Ucrania está a mundo y medio de nosotros.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "Puede alguien aportar alguna otra explicación o completar esta si es correcta?"

La mayoría de los artículos que he podido encontrar explicando el origen de  esta expresión incluyen la explicación que indicas, según la cual en la Antigua Grecia las pepitas de calabaza eran consideradas antiafrodisíacas. He encontrado también algunas referencias a que en la Edad Media los rosarios estaban hechos con pepitas de calabaza (para alejar los pensamientos impuros) e incluso se invitaba a comer pepitas de calabaza a tal efecto.

Sin embargo, he intentado verificar esto desde el otro lado (no que la calabaza sea realmente antiafrodisíaca, sino si realmente era considerada un antiafrodisíaco en la Antigua Grecia) y casi todos los artículos que he encontrado... hablan del origen de la expresión "dar calabazas". Así que no sé hasta qué punto esa referencia puede ser cierta.

También he encontrado [otros orígenes posibles](http://www.blogolengua.com/2011/09/dar-calabazas.html), en referencia al uso de calabazas huecas para aprender a nadar (al que ya apuntaba @blonfu en los comentarios). En ese artículo se lee:

> “Las calabazas sustentan en el agua a los que no saben nadar, que sin ellas se irían a lo hondo. Cuando alguno nos propone alguna cosa desproporcionada, solemos decir, **más calabazas**, dando a entender, que es disparate, **que puede significar cosa de aire de poco momento, y peso**. [...] **Echar a uno calabaza, es no responderle a lo que pide**, como el galán que saca la dama en el festín a bailar, y ella se excusa, dando a entender que es liviano y de poco seso, por querer salga a danzar con él, no siendo o su igual o de su gusto **o que le dejó en vacío hecho calabaza.**” <sub>(Covarrubias, Tesoro de la lengua castellana o española, 1611)</sub>

Recordemos que en español usamos `calabaza` para referirnos a varias frutas, por ejemplo la [calabaza almizclera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Butternut_squash) y la "tradicional".

En ese mismo articulo se elaboran un poco más todas estas ideas de cómo la calabaza, por antiafrodisíaca o por estar llena de aire, llega a asociarse con rechazo.

> [En contraposición al melón, que es el símbolo de la fecundidad, la abundancia y el lujo] la calabaza simboliza lo falso o de poco valor, porque resulta engañosa: promete mucho por su tamaño, pero defrauda por ser poco densa e insípida.
>
> “Calabaza: Por semejanza, se llama el melón que es insípido y no tiene dulce alguno” (Autoridades, 1729).
>
> “Te juzgué melón y me resultaste calabaza”. (Refrán)

Así que la asociación de calabaza con "frustración de deseos" (amorosos o académicos) parece radicar más en el hecho de que la calabaza es un fruto "engañoso" por prometer mucho pero luego dar menos de lo esperado.

También hay que destacar del artículo esta explicación sobre la diferencia entre el "dar calabazas" sentimental y académico y sus primeros registros en la literatura:

> Es raro oír que un profesor da calabazas, ‘suspende’, a un alumno: podría malinterpretarse, porque la expresión se ha ido especializando en el ámbito de las relaciones personales. [...] **el sentido de rechazo amoroso es anterior al de suspenso académico**, aunque en el primer Diccionario de la Academia (Autoridades, 1729) solo se recogiera la acepción de suspender y hubiera que esperar a la edición de 1780 para encontrar la de “desechar las mujeres la proposición de algún novio’